# prove that the coproduct of commutative rings with unity is the tensor product of the underlying abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

How to prove that the coproduct of commutative rings with unity is the tensor product of the underlying abelian groups?

I don't know where to start and how to finish. May I get some ideas or the proof.

Comment: You could prove it directly, or you could prove that the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Ring} \to \mathbf{AbGp}$ has a left adjoint (which is an example of a free–forgetful adjunction).

Comment: How would I prove it directly?

Comment: Write out the universal property of coproducts and verify that it's true in this case.

Comment: Let $A,B$ be commutative rings. Then there exists maps $i_1:A\to A\otimes B$ and $i_2:B\to A\otimes B$. Now suppose there exists a morphism $f_1: A\to C$ and $f_2:B\to C$. Then we need to produce a unique map $g: A\otimes B\to C$ such that diagrams commute. What properties do we have to produce such a map?

Comment: $g$ is defined on the usual generators for $A \otimes B$ by $g(a \otimes b) = f_1(a) \cdot f_2(b)$. You need to show this is well-defined and you also need to define a product on $A \otimes B$ that makes it into a commutative ring such that $g$ becomes a ring homomorphism.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative rings with unity. Then, the tensor product $A \otimes B$ as abelian groups is an abelian group.
To recall, this is the tensor product over the ring $\Bbb Z$. (A $\Bbb Z$-module is the same as an abelian group.)

Moreover, recall the (essence of) the universal property of tensor product: Given a $\Bbb Z$-bilinear map $\varphi: A \times B \to C$, we get a unique well-defined $\Bbb Z$-linear map $\tilde \varphi : A \otimes B \to C$ satisfying $\tilde \varphi(a \otimes b) = \varphi((a, b))$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

---

Now, we must first turn $A \otimes B$ into a ring. This is done by defining $$(a \otimes b) \cdot (a' \otimes b) := (aa') \otimes (bb')$$
and then extending it linearly.

We must check that the above makes sense.
First, for $(a, b) \in A \times B$, define the map $m_{a, b} : A \times B \to A \otimes B$ as $$m_{a, b}(a', b') = (aa') \otimes (bb').$$
For a fixed $(a, b) \in A \times B$, the map $m_{a, b}$ is bilinear. Thus, we get a well-defined linear map $\tilde m_{a, b} : A \otimes B \to A \otimes B$ given by the tensor property.

Now, $M : A \times B \to \operatorname{Hom}(A \otimes B, A \otimes B)$ given by $(a, b) \mapsto \tilde m_{a, b}$ is again bilinear. Thus, we get a well-defined map $\tilde M : A \otimes B \to \operatorname{Hom}(A \otimes B, A \otimes B)$ given by $$\tilde M(a \otimes b) = \tilde m_{a, b}.$$
Thus, our previous definition of the product in $A \otimes B$ makes sense since it is precisely
$$[\tilde M(a \otimes b)](a' \otimes b').$$
Moreover, the distributive property follows since $\tilde M$ and $\tilde m_{a, b}$ are linear maps. Associativity is easy to see. Moreover, the ring has a multiplicative identity, namely $1 \otimes 1$.

---

Now, for it to be the coproduct, we must give maps $A \xrightarrow{i_1} A \otimes B \xleftarrow{i_2} B$ and show that it satisfies the universal property.
The maps are the obvious ones, namely $a \mapsto a \otimes 1$ and $b \mapsto 1 \otimes b$. These are easily checked to be ring maps.

Now, suppose we are given ring maps $f_1 : A \to C$ and $f_2 : B \to C$.
We wish to define a ring map $g : A \otimes B \to C$ making the desired diagram commute. Moreover, it must be the unique such map.

Firstly, note that such a $g$, if it exists, is forced to satisfy
\begin{align}
g(a \otimes b) &= g((a \otimes 1)(1 \otimes b)) \\
&= g(a \otimes 1) g(1 \otimes b) \\
&= g(i_1(a)) g(i_2(b)) \\
&= f_1(a) f_2(b).
\end{align}

The above proves uniqueness since $g$ is completely determined on the generators. Moreover, it also tells us how we must define $g$.

Now, it is easy to check that $A \times B \to C$ defined by $(a, b) \mapsto f_1(a) f_2(b)$ is bilinear and thus, again, by the universal property of tensor, we get a well-defined map $A \otimes B \to C$ sending $a \otimes b \mapsto f_1(a) f_2(a)$ and we are done. (Why is this a ring map?)

Comment: Perfect answer, +1