# Non trivial colimit for rings in a finite diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

I’m trying to understand the concept of colimits for commutative rings, but unable to find a colimit(or at least a compliment) for a finite diagram of rings, is there a(non trivial) example for a compliment(and a colimit as a universal compliment) for a 2-3 rings diagram?

Comment: What's a "compliment" in this context?

Comment: For a diagram of rings and morphisms D, a compliment is defined as a ring A with a morphism from any ring J in D to A such that the diagram commutes

Comment: That would usually be called a cocone. Have you tried starting with thinking about coproducts? See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360305/prove-that-the-coproduct-of-commutative-rings-with-unity-is-the-tensor-product-o).

Comment: You could consider $\mathbb Z[1/m]\subset\mathbb Z[1/mn]\subset\cdots$ for positive (coprime) integers $m,n,\ldots$, all seen as subrings of $\mathbb Q$.